# POST Login with ActionScript 2.0

Tags: html, flash, actionscript, post, actionscript-2

I have created a pretty basic Flash website for a client and am having an issue programming a Client Login feature that he would like. Currently, if I navigate to the site and click Client Login, it takes me to a login page. The way I need this to work is -- within the Flash, using ActionScript 2.0 -- have the user enter their UserID and Password and click to login, which submits POST vars to the form action of the Client Login website.

Is this possible/legal to do from a different domain? How would I go about doing this, assuming it's possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
myVars = new LoadVars();
myVars.username = username.text;
myVars.password = pwd.text;
myVars.onLoad = function(success) {
        trace("yay!");
    else {
        trace("try again");    
    }
}
myVars.sendAndLoad("login.php", myVars, "POST");
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I get "yay!" with the code provided below (yours had an error in it). However, I need to be redirected to the resulting "logged-in" page. How do I do that?

```
myVars = new LoadVars();
myVars.txtUserID = "some_user";
myVars.txtPassword = "some_password";
myVars.__VIEWSTATE = "dDw3MTcxMTg3ODM7dDw7bDxpPDM+O2k8NT47PjtsPHQ8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPGRlbW87Pj47Oz47dDw7bDxpPDE+O2k8Mz47aTw1Pjs+O2w8dDxwPGw8VGV4dDs+O2w8YmFja2dyb3VuZC1jb2xvcjojZjZmNmY2XDtjb2xvcjojMzMzMzMzXDs7Pj47Oz47dDxwPDtwPGw8c3R5bGU7PjtsPHdpZHRoOjEwMHB4XDs7Pj4+Ozs+O3Q8cDw7cDxsPHN0eWxlOz47bDx3aWR0aDoxMDBweFw7Oz4+Pjs7Pjs+Pjs+Pjs+56k0UDxn5ED61lGLjP0fIkStm6o=";
myVars.onLoad = function(success) {
    if (success)
    {
        trace("yay!");
    } else {
        trace("try again");    
    }
}
myVars.sendAndLoad("http://www.buildertrend.net/loginFrame.aspx?builderID=35&bgcolor=%23f6f6f6&fcolor=%23333333&uwidth=100&pwidth=100", myVars, "POST");
```

Comment: Well, if you're ending up with a NON-Flash page as a result, you are better of putting a hidden form on your parent HTML page and populating the form with JavaScript, which you can call from Flash,  and submitting it.

Comment: If you need help with the JavaScript let me know.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I could manage, but I've been given a different direction from my manager. So, I don't get to try it out. From my experience, though, I'm sure that would have worked. Thanks for your help.