# Flash AS1/AS2 : quick + dirty SOAP msg send with minimum overheads?

Tags: flash, soap, actionscript-2

Is there a way to send a simple SOAP message to a web service on another domain, while not caring about the response (this is simply a small data push) in an old flash app?

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: I believe you could just post the xml. If you need to know how to do that see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231693/post-login-with-actionscript-2-0

Comment: I've merged your unregistered accounts. You can now accept the answer that you like.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest thing I can think of:

1. Drag the **WebService Connector** component from the **Components Panel** to the **Stage**.
2. Give it an **instance name** and set the **operation** in the **Components Inspector**.
3. Trigger it via Actionscript:

   yourWebServiceConnector.trigger();

That should be it.

A more comprehensive guide on as2 data components is available [here](http://www.flash-db.com/services/tutorials/mxclasses/mxwebservices.php).

HTH,
Georrge