# AS2: Is it possible for flash to POST data to external server?

Tags: actionscript, post, actionscript-2

I need flash to POST some data to an external server is this possible in AS2? Can't get an answer on google and want to know before I implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the similar question:
[POST Login with ActionScript 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231693/post-login-with-actionscript-2-0)

You need to check if the server allows the request from your current server (i.e. where flash file is host). See http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html