# Data Collection and Transfer from Local Flash File

Tags: flash, actionscript, shared-objects

I have inherited a large flash script (written in AS2) which runs an experiment and saves data using the `SharedObject` framework.  This script will be given to users to run on their local machines, probably on a USB drive or a CD.  What is the easiest way to transfer the locally stored `SharedObject` either to this USB drive or to send it electronically?  Is it possible to store the `SharedObject` in the same location as the swf file (e.g., on the USB drive?)  I see that hooking up flash with PHP is possible, but is there a purely flash way to send this data via email, ftp or another protocol to a server?

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid trying to use the file(s) that contain the SharedObject data. Even if you copied these files to a USB drive, you'd then have to write an app that knows how to open each one and get the data out.  SharedObject data is user specific, so it's not clear how that later process would work.

Unfortunately, I don't have any knowledge of programming in AS2 -- only AS3.

For the most part, in Actionscript use HTTP to send data to the server. There are other ways, but this is obviously the most straight forward means.

If you were programming in AS3, you could use the URLLoader, URLRequest, URLVariables classes together to do an HTTP POST or GET to the server.

Here's some links I found on doing HTTP POST/GET with AS2:

- [POST Login with ActionScript 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231693/post-login-with-actionscript-2-0)
- http://www.flash-here.com/tutorials/flash_loadvars_sample.html

Answer (score 1):

You can save a file to the local file system in ActionScript 2.0 with the [`FileReference.save()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) method. This opens a dialogue box which allows the user to save the file to a location of their choice. You would be free to choose the most appropriate format for the outputted data.

Comment: Good idea, this is closer to what they seem to be looking for :)

Comment: Sorry Sunil, I seem to be gate-crashing all your answers tonight. Thanks for the supportive comments :)

Comment: This looks promising, but I'd really like to be able to make sure that the file goes into the right place.  Is it possible to get the location of the script being run, and suggest/insist that the file be saved there?

Comment: You can get the full path of the SWF from the environmental variable _url. I suppose you could remove the filename from this path and suggest (I don't think you can insist) that the user saves the file to that location. Also, from what I've seen, the default location of the browse dialogue will generally be the directory from which the Flash is being run which may be useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments - I'm working on too many projects right now, but if this turns out to work for me, I'll 'accept' your answer! :)